# How do I switch perspectives Eclipse?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing a C++ application with Eclipse CDT but sometimes I need to work with Java projects.

How do you switch between the Java and C++ eclipse environments?

Comment: IIRC its the menu option: `Window->Perspective->Open Perspective->...` and then hunt around for the `Java` perspective.

Answer (score 2):

The general Eclipse shortcut for switching perspectives is:

```
Ctrl+F8
```

If you hold down Ctrl longer, you can choose to which perspective to jump.

See Eclipse tutorial about shortcuts:
[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can change perspectives by accessing `Window>Perspective>Open Perspective>..`, however there are some buttons on the right of the toolbar for switching perspectives and a button for adding new perspective switch buttons, so you can use those to switch perspectives rapidly.